# How to record two windows at once using ffmpeg?

Tags: windows, ffmpeg, gdi, screen-capture

I'm currently using this code:

```
ffmpeg -f gdigrab -framerate 30 -i title="Chrome" -b:v 3M  output.flv
```

To capture a specific window title.

Would like to ask how I could also capture a second window title, and save both streams to just one output file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basic syntax would be

`ffmpeg -f gdigrab -framerate 30 -i title="Chrome" -f gdigrab -framerate 30 -i title="OtherWindow" -map 0 -map 1 -b:v 3M output.mp4`

(You can only save one video stream in a FLV file)

Comment: Hello, the output file contains only the video of the window in the first `title` parameter.

Comment: Show the output of `ffmpeg -i output.mp4`

Comment: Output so long to paste it here, i have upload it to pastebin https://pastebin.com/D0jDQ9gN

Comment: I see two video streams in the output file with resolution `960x480` and `713x694`.

Comment: There is, the problem i didn't know i need to enable the stream of the second output in the player. Currently im using VLC, you need to go on VLC > Video Track > And enable the second track. Gyan the recording is using too much CPU, there are any 'better settings' i could use? I dont need pretty recording, im using it to debug, being able to at least read the text in the prompt is enough.

Comment: Remove `-b:v 3M` and add `-preset superfast`

Comment: It shows this message at the beginning: `Thread message queue blocking; consider raising the thread_queue_size option (current value: 8)`  any problem ?

Comment: Add `-thread_queue_size 1024` before each `-i`.

Comment: Is possible to capture the window title bar? currently not being captured.